# Run VMware player in shell mode?

Tags: linux, redhat, shell, vmware-player

Is there a way to run vmware player in shell mode? I'm accessing the PC remotely and only have access to the RHEL shell and not the GUI.

Thank you.

Regards,
Rayne

Answer (score 1):

quick answer seems to be no -headless running was restricted to vmware server- you could probably do the same thing with virtualbox

Answer (score 1):

If you install Vmware VIX you can use vmrun to launch vmware player without GUI.